# Disable A2DP Output on Android for TTS

Tags: android, bluetooth, text-to-speech, a2dp

I have an Android 4.1 device which is connected to A2DP stereo speaker.

My app uses TTS (Text-To-Speech) and the AudioTrack class for streaming a custom sound to the speaker.

Is it possible to use the phone speaker for TTS.

For exmaple:

1. Sound is streaming to A2DP device
2. Stop sound output
3. Switch to phone speaker
4. Start TTS
5. Swith back to A2DP
6. Start stream again

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I don't think this is feasible. If you just wanted to connect any bluetooth device and have the phone's speaker for the TTS this can be done easily by changing the "Media device" setting in the pairing of the bluetooth device. Changing this setting programmatically I think cannot be done.

EDIT:
To check this setting go to your paired devices:[image]
and if you click on the small cog next to the specific device you will see this option (media audio)[image]

And when you want to disconnect just close the bluetooth socket and close the streams. Something like:

```
if (streamInput != null)
    {
        streamInput.close();
        streamInput = null;
    }
    if (streamOutput != null)
    {
        streamOutput.close();
        streamOutput = null;
    }
    if (bluetoothSocket != null)
    {
        bluetoothSocket.close();
        bluetoothSocket = null;
    }
```

(This will close the connection - the device will remain paired. And if you want to disable the bluetooth just do a `bluetoothAdapter.disable();` )

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

How can i change the "Media device" setting for TTS? I don't find a settings item for that...

And is it possible to programmatically disconnect the bluetooth speaker?

Comment: The "Call audio" settings item isn't available at my device (Nexus S with Android 4.1.2)

Comment: The media audio is the one that matters. The screenshots are from a Galaxy S3 with v4.1.1)